# How can I use classes like "1/2" or "1/4"?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a simple grid in HTML/CSS and therefore I decided to name them "1/2", 1/4", "2/4" etc. but these classes arent valid in css. I know there is a workaround out there but after a 30 minutes research I thought here I could get my answer.

```
.1/2{
  width: 50%;
}
```

I specifically need a workaround that I didn't found anywhere in this forum or on another site. Dont suggest me a generel name convention for declaring my css classes pls, I know what's valid and whats not, but I need this workaround.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/resigopiji/1/edit?html,css,output But I'm sure the W3 Consortium will kill a kitten every time you use it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Oh nos, not the kittens!! Kidding aside though, that's a great workaround!

Comment: Tip: All capital nicks don't look very well on the first spot, I suggest to become simply "Lueh".

Comment: Can I just say that while, _technically_, escaping the classes in the stylesheet as `.\31\2f\32` is the correct solution, it is not nice on the eyes, not to mention it's a maintainer's nightmare. I would stick to words that don't need escaping, so that you will know that a class name of `topleft` always corresponds to a selector of `.topleft`.

Comment: @MrLister Perhaps I didn't get it right but I couldn't manage to escape `/`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8ot44tgm/).

Comment: @MrLister Oh, sorry, I totally overlooked you were using `\2f` to encode `/`. Certainly, that works.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you for your help! I just needed the solution you mentioned first and I was not remembering it by myself, I did a little change in your bin so you can see what I try to make with it :) http://jsbin.com/mojawepiga/1/edit?html,css,output